# Should I be concerned with symmetry/neatness?

Tags: modeling, topology

I often find myself stumbling when trying to make a model that consists of oddly shaped parts, or with different required poly density's across (i.e. adding round arms to a square body). It can get very tricky to get the shape I want but keep everything perfectly aligned. Should I be more concerned with the topology, or should I be more concerned with the final shape?

For example something like this:
[image: a cube with unwholesome subdeivision]

Comment: The question is too vague, this depends on what you use the model for.

Comment: any model,whether organic or inorganic has this problem. I've seen this factor disregarded in tutorial videos, but at the same time I see instances where some blender users stress over the correctness of the mesh and topology.

Comment: It largely depends on what you are going to use the model for, rendering, simulating or gaming. Almost never do you need to worry about symmetry. What almost always matters is topology (could be called neatness). Use mostly quads (this depends on the usage of the model) and have edges flow along edges in the shape you are trying to make. In your models I see several ngons with more than 4 vertices, this is bad if you intend to use a subsurf modifier. If this question gets reopened, I will show you a way to solve it.

Comment: It is usually acceptable to have large polys in big flat areas and lots of polys in detailed areas. It's putting lots of little polys over the entire mesh when they aren't needed that get frowned upon.

Comment: is it worse to do what happened in the example picture to make fine details, or is it worse to make the whole thing into tiny units for that purpose?